# Sales system datamodel (Logical)

Tags: data-modeling, object-oriented-analysis

I have tried to make a logical data model, but I am not totally sure if it is modeled right. It is a very cut-down and basic model, but overall I want to know if it is modeled the way is should be.

[image: Data Model - Sales system]

Furthermore, how do I convert this into a class model in object oriented programming? 
I guess I need:

```
Class Customer: int id, string name 
Class Order: int id, string date, Customer object 
Class Item: int id, string itemName, string item Desc 
Class OrderItem: ?
```

Comment: You wouldn't need an `OrderItem` class.  You could have a list of items in your `Order` class.  Also in your data model you don't need the relationship line between `Orders` and `Items` since there is a junction table between the two for the many to many relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jmw5598. Makes sense, if i remove the relationship between Orders and items, is the model then righly modeled?

Comment: yes. and you don't need a class to represent the `Order_Items` junction table.  You can use a data structure like a list, array, or set in your `Order` class to represent a collection of `Items` for the `Order`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I a list would be perfect in this scenario. @jmw5598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your data model, you don't need the relationship line between `Orders` and `Items`.  You're using the junction table `Order_Items` to represent that many to many relationship.

As for the class models, you won't need a class to model the junction table.  You can simply model it with a collection of `Item` in your `Order` class.  The relationship between the `Order` and `Item` class is a composition relationship.  You can think of it as: An `Order` has-a `Item` or an `Order` has-s collection of `Item`.

Here is how you can model the `Order` class in java.

```
public class Order {
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private Customer customer;
    private List<Item> items;  // you could use other collection types as well.

    ...
}
```

Edit:

Also for your many side of the relationships, you may consider using "one through many" line (crows foot with a line)" as opposed to "zero through many" (crows foot with circle).  A order generally has atleast 1 item and atleast 1 customer.  An order isn't an order without a customer or items.